# Kubeadm Init failed at boot up control plane (kubelet isn't running or healthy)

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, kubelet

I am using centos7 and using the below command to the bootstrap Kubernetes control plane in Master node :

```
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16 -v=5
```

and below is the error :

```
I1124 11:11:51.842474    5446 waitcontrolplane.go:87] [wait-control-plane] Waiting for the API server to be healthy
[wait-control-plane] Waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as static Pods from directory "/etc/kubernetes/manifests". This can take up to 4m0s
[kubelet-check] Initial timeout of 40s passed.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp [::1]:10248: connect: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp [::1]:10248: connect: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp [::1]:10248: connect: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp [::1]:10248: connect: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp [::1]:10248: connect: connection refused.

    Unfortunately, an error has occurred:
            timed out waiting for the condition

    This error is likely caused by:
            - The kubelet is not running
            - The kubelet is unhealthy due to a misconfiguration of the node in some way (required cgroups disabled)

    If you are on a systemd-powered system, you can try to troubleshoot the error with the following commands:
            - 'systemctl status kubelet'
            - 'journalctl -xeu kubelet'

    Additionally, a control plane component may have crashed or exited when started by the container runtime.
    To troubleshoot, list all containers using your preferred container runtimes CLI.

    Here is one example of how you may list all Kubernetes containers running in docker:
            - 'docker ps -a | grep kube | grep -v pause'
            Once you have found the failing container, you can inspect its logs with:
            - 'docker logs CONTAINERID'

couldn't initialize a Kubernetes cluster
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/init.runWaitControlPlanePhase
        /workspace/anago-v1.19.4-rc.0.51+5f1e5cafd33a88/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/init/waitcontrolplane.go:114
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).Run.func1
        /workspace/anago-v1.19.4-rc.0.51+5f1e5cafd33a88/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:234
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).visitAll
        /workspace/anago-v1.19.4-rc.0.51+5f1e5cafd33a88/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:422
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).Run
        /workspace/anago-v1.19.4-rc.0.51+5f1e5cafd33a88/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:207
```

systemctl status kubelet output

```
[root@vm1 centos]# systemctl status kubelet
● kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
           └─10-kubeadm.conf
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-11-25 07:28:41 UTC; 9s ago
     Docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/
  Process: 4634 ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS (code=exited, status=255)
 Main PID: 4634 (code=exited, status=255)

Nov 25 07:28:42 vm1.novalocal kubelet[4634]: goroutine 509 [select]:
Nov 25 07:28:42 vm1.novalocal kubelet[4634]: k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/google/cadvisor/manager.(*manager).globalHousekeeping(0xc00045...0dff140)
Nov 25 07:28:42 vm1.novalocal kubelet[4634]: /workspace/anago-v1.19.4-rc.0.51+5f1e5cafd33a88/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8...5 +0x145
Nov 25 07:28:42 vm1.novalocal kubelet[4634]: created by k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/google/cadvisor/manager.(*manager).Start
Nov 25 07:28:42 vm1.novalocal kubelet[4634]: /workspace/anago-v1.19.4-rc.0.51+5f1e5cafd33a88/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8...9 +0x4b9
Nov 25 07:28:42 vm1.novalocal kubelet[4634]: goroutine 510 [select]:
Nov 25 07:28:42 vm1.novalocal kubelet[4634]: k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/google/cadvisor/manager.(*manager).updateMachineInfo(0xc000453...0dff1a0)
Nov 25 07:28:42 vm1.novalocal kubelet[4634]: /workspace/anago-v1.19.4-rc.0.51+5f1e5cafd33a88/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8...57 +0xd4
Nov 25 07:28:42 vm1.novalocal kubelet[4634]: created by k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/google/cadvisor/manager.(*manager).Start
Nov 25 07:28:42 vm1.novalocal kubelet[4634]: /workspace/anago-v1.19.4-rc.0.51+5f1e5cafd33a88/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8...3 +0x53b
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

kubelet journal output

```
Nov 25 07:33:08 vm1.novalocal kubelet[9576]: /workspace/anago-v1.19.4-rc.0.51+5f1e5cafd33a88/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/google/cadvisor/manager/manager.go:319 +0x4b9
Nov 25 07:33:08 vm1.novalocal kubelet[9576]: goroutine 507 [select]:
Nov 25 07:33:08 vm1.novalocal kubelet[9576]: k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/google/cadvisor/manager.(*manager).updateMachineInfo(0xc000732c80, 0xc000df1800)
Nov 25 07:33:08 vm1.novalocal kubelet[9576]: /workspace/anago-v1.19.4-rc.0.51+5f1e5cafd33a88/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/google/cadvisor/manager/manager.go:357 +0xd4
Nov 25 07:33:08 vm1.novalocal kubelet[9576]: created by k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/google/cadvisor/manager.(*manager).Start
Nov 25 07:33:08 vm1.novalocal kubelet[9576]: /workspace/anago-v1.19.4-rc.0.51+5f1e5cafd33a88/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/google/cadvisor/manager/manager.go:323 +0x53b
```

Version of docker and kubectl

```
[root@vm1 centos]# kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.4", GitCommit:"d360454c9bcd1634cf4cc52d1867af5491dc9c5f", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-11-11T13:17:17Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
[root@vm1 centos]# docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.13
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        4484c46d9d
 Built:             Wed Sep 16 17:03:45 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false
```

Docker info

```
[root@vm1 centos]# docker info
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 1
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 1
 Images: 11
 Server Version: 19.03.13
 Storage Driver: devicemapper
  Pool Name: docker-253:1-41943508-pool
  Pool Blocksize: 65.54kB
  Base Device Size: 10.74GB
  Backing Filesystem: xfs
  Udev Sync Supported: true
  Data file: /dev/loop0
  Metadata file: /dev/loop1
  Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
  Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
  Data Space Used: 1.144GB
  Data Space Total: 107.4GB
  Data Space Available: 39.08GB
  Metadata Space Used: 1.54MB
  Metadata Space Total: 2.147GB
  Metadata Space Available: 2.146GB
  Thin Pool Minimum Free Space: 10.74GB
  Deferred Removal Enabled: true
  Deferred Deletion Enabled: true
  Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
  Library Version: 1.02.170-RHEL7 (2020-03-24)
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 8fba4e9a7d01810a393d5d25a3621dc101981175
 runc version: dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 3.10.0-229.7.2.el7.x86_64
 Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 2
 Total Memory: 3.703GiB
 Name: vm1.novalocal
 ID: OJIR:5IGM:GPJA:D4ZC:7UU6:SQUP:I424:JMAL:LNL5:EQB7:DKFH:XPSB
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: the devicemapper storage-driver is deprecated, and will be removed in a future release.
WARNING: devicemapper: usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use.
         Use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` to specify a custom block storage device.
```

Anybody can help me with this? It looks obviously like the kubelet is not working fine..but i dont know how to look and fix it...

Comment: Are you following some guide to install? Did you check if the `kubelet` is running? What is the docker version ?

Comment: Well, start with what the error message says. Run `systemctl status kubelet` and `journalctl -xeu kubelet | less` to check kubelet status. Try to check docker containers as advised (if you are using docker as your container runtime). Also `kubectl version`, `docker version` and `docker info` won't harm (again, if it's docker you are using).

Comment: @KoopaKiller it's showing "Activating"

Comment: @OlesyaBolobova see my update on the question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a very old Linux kernel [released in 2015](https://access.redhat.com/articles/3078).
No container will work with it.
Upgrade the kernel, reinstall your docker and kubernetes tools and try again.